# How to sign multiple gpg keys in a bash script (non-interactively)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, gpg

I'm setting up some keys for our team. I want to make a bash script that will sign all the (known) keys that I have just imported. I want to sign the keys without prompts (non-interactive).

Here's what I have.

```
for key in $(gpg2 -k --with-colons | grep pub: | cut -d ":" -f 5); do
  gpg2 --fingerprint $key
  # TODO: check if the key is already signed; if not, sign it
  gpg2 --batch --yes --sign-key $key
done
```

The above is missing a check (which is not critical as gpg2 seems to do the right thing if the key is already signed). But more importantly it also fails to answer some prompts with "yes".

The other related questions all involved answers that required interactivity (except in one case which used xdotool to enter keystrokes, and which I don't find satisfactory).

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the output from `gpg --export-ownertrust`.

For example:

```
FP="9274E588E866A10B713C9CCD9EB3AD425D1CCC11"
echo "Checking Trust for $FP" 
TRUST_LEVEL=$(gpg --export-ownertrust| grep $FP | awk  -F : '{print $2}')
case $TRUST_LEVEL in
    2)
        echo "I don't know or won't say (export: 2)"
        ;;
    3)
        echo "I do NOT trust            (export: 3)"
        ;;
    4)
        echo "I trust marginally        (export: 4)"
        ;;
    5)
        echo "I trust fully             (export: 5)"
        ;;
    6)
        echo "I trust ultimately        (export: 6)"
        ;;
    *)
        echo -n "Trust level unknown, key not imported or not signed?"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Can you explain how this snippet is used to sign my keys non-interactively? It looks like it just echos some text. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, sorry; I thought that you were wanting to trust the key if you did not already trust it. This answer was for checking to see if it was trusted so that you could automate trusting the key conditionally. I see now that you are trying to check and see if it's already signed. That I don't yet know.

Comment: In regards to the TODO for checking if a key is singed: 

gpg --with-fingerprint --with-colons --fixed-list-mode --list-sigs <KEY_FINGERPRINT> | awk -F ":" '/^sig/ {print $5}' | sort -u

Comment: Thanks for replying. It would help me if you could add your comment into the answer so that I can try to understand what you are suggesting. I do want to trust the key, and do make the script do that instead of having to do it interactively. I still cannot tell whether or not your answer is a solution.